# Render text with HTML tags in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I have this data:

```
{ 
  "text":"<h1>hello</h1><p style={{backgroundColor:blue}}>Paragraph text</p>",
  "type":"bold"
},
```

But when I show it in my page, it shows up with the tags h1 and p and style. How can I print this variable, and have the tags work as well?

This is my js:

```
<div key={index}>
    {descriere.type === "bold" ? (
    <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
        {data.text}
    </p>
    ) : (
    <p style={{ color: "purple" }}>
        {data.text}
    </p>
    )}
</div>
```

I also tried printing it inside a div tag and the same issue.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property to render HTML. here is the  [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample111-uz9tz)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), it is widely used with gatsby where you query the markdowns for content.

```
<div key={index}>
  {descriere.type === 'bold' ? (
    <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: data.text} />
    </p>
  ) : (
    <p style={{ color: 'purple' }}>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: data.text} />
    </p>
  )}
</div>
```